# How to split paths on Windows consistently

Tags: python, string, split

I get very confused when building paths on windows:

```
HDF_OUTPUT = f'{__file__}'.split('\\')
print(HDF_OUTPUT)


HDF_OUTPUT = f'{__file__}'.split('/')
print(HDF_OUTPUT)
```

Output:

```
['C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/tsfresh/file.py']
['C:', 'Users', 'Artur', 'Desktop', 'tsfresh', 'file.py']
```

In this example the second approach worked, but it's not always this way. Sometimes the first approach results in the right split and sometimes the second approach results in the right split. There seem to be a problem with the `/` and the `\\` operator.

I want this split:

```
['C:', 'Users', 'Artur', 'Desktop', 'tsfresh', 'file.py']
```

How do I get consistency into this? Is there a proper way of handling paths?

Comment: Windows paths use `\ `,not `/`. Even when a program uses forward slashes, the *real* paths sent to the Win32 API use backslashes. The forward slash is used to provide parameters to commands

Comment: If you know the string doesn't contain arguments, you can use a regex that splits using both characters. `/` is invalid in a path, there's no chance of stumbling on a file named `123/456.txt`

Comment: When I do `.split('\')` it doesn't even work because it turns the `)` into a string

Comment: You forgot to escape the backslash

Comment: Use [`os.path.normcase(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)

Comment: Each OS might have different ways of handling paths (i.e. windows and lixus with `/` and `\`) , I'd recommend you to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib)

Comment: Doesn't your code there only give you the filename and not the full path? Is that the same code that you are running?

Comment: In any case, you should use a library to parse and manipulate paths instead of simple splitting. Splitting doesn't understand `..` for example. Quite a few bugs and exploits are caused by naive splitting or joining paths. Apart from `os.path.normcase`, you can use `os.path.split`, `os.path.splitext` etc. `os.path.walk` will split *and* process each directory in the path

Comment: @RahulP the `__file__` variable gives the whole path of the python file the code is executed in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, the built-in default of handling paths is through the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library.

```py
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(r'C:\mypath\to\my\file.txt')
print(p.parts)
# ('C:\\', 'mypath', 'to', 'my', 'file.txt')
```